# Using Moq and Mock objects - my list count is always 0 when it should not be

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am not sure why my get list method is bringing back 0 records in my test but when I run my application it pulls back a list of 5 items.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestHasListOfSurveys()
{
    var mockRepository = new Mock<ISurveyListRepository>();
    var mockModel = new List<SurveyList>();
    string testDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).ToShortDateString();

    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSurveyList(testDate)).Returns(mockModel);

    var testClass = new SurveyListModel(mockRepository.Object);
    var testModel = testClass.GetSurveyList(testDate);

    mockRepository.VerifyAll();

    Assert.IsTrue(testModel.Count > 0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

Okay I think I see what I did now. So if I change it to:

```
    var mockModel = new List<SurveyList>();
    mockModel.Add(new SurveyList { SurveyID = 1, SurveyName = "test1" });
    mockModel.Add(new SurveyList { SurveyID = 2, SurveyName = "test2" });
    mockModel.Add(new SurveyList { SurveyID = 3, SurveyName = "test3" });
```

then it will have a count and be fine and then my mock object has items.

Comment: isn't `mockModel` just an empty list. Why would you expect a count > 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISurveyListRepository` dependency is replaced by a mock in your test, your application probably uses an other implementation.

```
var mockModel = new List<SurveyList>();
mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSurveyList(testDate)).Returns(mockModel);
```

These lines make the mock return an empty list, that's probably why your test is failing.If you add some items to the list, your test will pass. On the other hand, the application uses a class implementing `ISurveyListRepository`. Find that class and you will see why it's returning 5 items.

Comment: I updated my post. So with my new edit then the test is valid?

Comment: It should be. If the test documents the implementation and makes sense for you, it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSurveyList(testDate)).Returns(mockModel);
```

you should write something like :

```
mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSurveyList(It.IsAny<String>)).Returns(mockModel);
```

otherwise, your mock will not be used .

anyway, if you tell it to return `mockModel` which is empty, you will get obviously empty list.

Comment: testDate is a `string`. It.IsAny<string> would work but shouldnt be the issue here.

Comment: Is Returns telling it what GetSurveyList will return as a value? I thought Returns would tell it what to put the value it gets into. Maybe that's where I'm screwing up.

Comment: Yes, .Returns() says what will be the return object of the GetSurveyList function .

Comment: If I take away Returns then testModel is null. How can I make it return a list populated by the database? Or is that not a proper unit test?

Comment: what do you mean by "list populate by database" ? maybe you mean return a list populated with data. anyway, so you create a list : var myList = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 56, 7 }; For E.G and then setups .Returns(myList) . if you want to get the data from the database - then, yes this is wrong and you should not do this at all in that particular test.